# How to restrict jQuery dataTable from copy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my application I am showing data in jQuery dataTable but according to requirement I want to restrict user from copying data using mouse or keyboard.I do have buttons in each row of dataTable which will be clickable.
I'am playing around with below code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 65 && e.ctrlKey) { //ctrl+A
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert("Hi Team");
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: You can't.  Once you've given the data to the user, the user has the data.  They can do whatever they like with it.

Comment: I know even after restricting mouse or keyboard(if possible) I won't be able to restrict print screen but would like to try restricting ctrl+c and right click=> copy

Comment: You don't fully understand, even if you restrict ctrl+c or rc-copy (bad practice imo) they still will be able to get the information if they want to because it's clientside.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to disable selection on the fields that you don't want to be copied. It is still possible to copy them using other methods but it is a sufficient solution for most cases in my opinion.

**CSS class for disabling selection.**

```
.disable-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
  -moz-user-select: none;    
  -ms-user-select: none;      
  user-select: none;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7vswp3g/

Answer (score 0):

Browser's Dev tools make this impossible, as long as you writing some output to the webpage and even disable it, People can press F12 or simply right-click and inspect then copy it.